# Java Tic Tac Toe architecture

Tags: java

I'm currently having a major brain fart :).

My plan was to build a simple swing based tic tac toe application in Java.  I had planned for the app to allow for one player, two player local and two player remote options.  I've got the one and two player local versions working fine but am struggling to get my head around the two player remote option.

Worth noting in the Netbeans project I have the gui in a separate package from the logic.

I've fried my brain thinking about all the options.

1. Like having a client server architecture but then if the client is running on a different pc than the logic this slows down the one player and two player local versions for no reason.
2. I'm thinking the entire application (gui + logic) should be distributed amongst the various pc's on the home wirless network.  That way players can play one and two player local games without any unneccesary lag time and see if anyone else is available for a two player remote version.  The question if I go this way is who's logic acts as the server - how does that work?

Is option 2 the best / only way of going about this because this isn't just a networked game?

Are there any other ways of going about this?

I know doing a tic tac toe game with just a remote game option would be a simple case of a client server architecture but having one player and then a networked version in the same app is tricky.

Thanks,

Paul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you could do this without actual server -- you can make it like client/host.

When user wants to be host, he sends UDP broadcast packet, with information on what ip, and what game he wants to play. everyone who wants to join can catch this packet.

When user wants to join, he listens to broadcast packet, and joins to the one he recieved.

Every player could do his own logic, and send his move to other player -- other side should only check is the move legal -- because maybe someone wants to hack your game :D

Comment: If my wife tries to hack my game she's in deep trouble :).  Thanks for the help guys, helps to talk these things through sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

The application should be installed on each client. For the remote 2-player  mode, you should implement your own P2P protocol to send actions from one player to the other and to keep track of the evolution of the game.

In a few words, each client should have its own model of the game locally which it updates whenever either the local player makes "a move" or the remote user sends (through the protocol) "a move".

Of course, if you need to keep track of statistics like scores, points, etc, you will need a central server to store this. But the actual game should take place in a P2P mode, with no need for a server.